# Error when sorting text file alphabetically

Tags: python

For my work, I have to be able to sort the scores of the user's quiz in a text file alphabetically. When I however use:

```
with open(filename, 'a') as f:
        f = open(filename, "r")
        lines = [line for line in f if line.strip()]
        f.close()
        lines.sort()
```

And then to print the scores via the Python shell when the user requests I used:

```
if get_bool_input("Do you wish to view previous results for your class"):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        print(f.read())
```

However it does not sort the scores but keeps them in the order that they were submitted, shown here:

```
Do you wish to view previous results for your classyes
Kyle : 4
Dan : 0
Jana : 0
Kyle : 0
Kyle : 0
Kyle : 9
Kyle : 6
Bob : 2
Bobby : 1
Kyle : 1
Kyle : 0
Kyle : 1
Kyle : 10
Bobby Mclobby : 7
Bobby Mcdobby : 5
Kyle Cliffe : 9
```

Here is the whole code for those that are wondering:

```
import random
import operator

OPERATIONS = [
    (operator.add, "+"),
    (operator.mul, "*"),
    (operator.sub, "-")
    ]

NB_QUESTIONS = 10

def get_int_input(prompt=''):
    while True:
      try:
        return int(input(prompt))
      except ValueError:
        print("Not a valid input (integer is expected)")

def get_bool_input(prompt=''):
    while True:
        val = input(prompt).lower()
        if val == 'yes':
            return True
        elif val == 'no':
            return False
        else:
            print("Not a valid input (yes/no is expected)")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    name = input("What is your name?").title()
    class_name = input("Which class do you wish to input results for? ")
    print(name, ", Welcome to the OCR Controlled Assessment Maths Test")

    score = 0
    for _ in range(NB_QUESTIONS):
        num1 = random.randint(1,25)
        num2 = random.randint(1,25)
        op, symbol = random.choice(OPERATIONS)
        print("What is", num1, symbol, num2)
        if get_int_input() == op(num1, num2):
            print("Correct")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("Incorrect")

    print("Well done", name, "you scored", score, "/", NB_QUESTIONS)

    filename = class_name + ".txt"

    with open(filename, 'a') as f:
        f.write(str(name) + " : " + str(score) + '\n')

    with open(filename, 'a') as f:
        f = open(filename, "r")
        lines = [line for line in f if line.strip()]
        f.close()
        lines.sort()

    if get_bool_input("Do you wish to view previous results for your class"):
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            print(f.read())
    else:
        input ("Press any key to exit")
```

Comment: The `with` construct opens the and assigns the handle to the variable `f` in this case. You should not be doing this: `f = open(filename, "r")` inside the `with`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not modifying the data of the file.

Since you already have read and sorted the lines, why don't you just print it directly from the variable like so

```
if get_bool_input("Do you wish to view previous results for your class"):
    for line in lines:
        print line
```